# Getting a PDF out of the SSH to the own system

Tags: ssh

Given:

Connection to the Uni's secure shell like this:

```
me@my_computer~$ ssh <my_name>@unixyz.cs.xy.com 
Password:***********

Welcome to Unixyz. You now can access a terminal on system unixyz:

my_name@unixyz~$ ls
Desktop Documents Pictures Music desired_document.pdf
my_name@unixyz-$
```

Taks/Question:

Getting the desired_document.pdf to my own system. I have thought of some options so far:

1)Since i can access an editor like nano I could write a C/Java programm , compile it in the home directory and make that program send the pdf. Problem with that: Had to code a client on the Uni machine and a server on my own system. On top of that I only know how to transfer text given to the stdin and no pdf's. And its obviously too much work for the given task

2) I found some vague information about commands: `scp` and `sftp`. Unfortunately, I can not figure out how it is done exactly.

The latter is basicly my questions: Are the commands `scp` and `sftp` valid options for doing the desired and how are they used?

---

EDIT:

I received a first answer and the problem persists: As stated, i use:

scp me@ server.cs.xyz.com:/path/topdf /some/local/dir

which gives me:

/some/local/dir: no such file or directory

Comment: Take a look at `scp` or `sftp`. They do exactly what you are looking for. I suggest you simply read their manual pages: `man scp`.

Comment: I did. But i really cant figure it out exactly

Comment: It says: ` scp benutzerx@server1:datei1 datei2 benutzery@server2` like do I have to set up an own server or something?

Comment: No, that is the complex form using two servers. You can use the simple form: Just like a normal file copy command: `scp user@remoteSystem:/path/to/source/file /path/to/local/target/`. As easy as that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure in which environment you are.
Do you use Linux or Windows as your every-day operating system?

If you are using windows, there are some ui-based scp/ssh implementations that enable you to transfer these files using an explorer based ui.

For example there is https://winscp.net/

Comment: I got my mistake. I launched scp from the remote server, not my own machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed use `scp` to do exacty that, and it's easier than it might look:

`scp your_username@ unixyz.cs.xy.com:path/to/desired_document.pdf /some/local/dir`

The key is the colon after the servername where you add your path

Optionally you can pass in the password as well, but that's bad practice, for obvious reasons.

Comment: The man page states scp userx@server1:data1 data2 usery@server2 which to my looks like giving 2 data names? And why @server? Do i have to setup an own ssh server?

Comment: see my edit, it seems not to know or find my directory

Answer (score 0):

I actually got the answer myself and the error that I was having. Both, the guy with the answer and the commentor where right. BUT:
scp must be launched when you are in YOUR terminal, I always tried to do it while  I was connected to the remote server.

2 hours wasted because of that.